# create Cocos2D Infinite Background Picture

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I  want to move a background picture continuously from left to right. I got a refrence from 
[infinite-background picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15099096/cocos2d-infinite-background-picture)

but in this the background image is moving right to left but i want from left to right. i tried to make changes in the above code, but this is not working for me.. 
can anyone please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to just change - to + for x and reverse the if conditions...

Try this:

```
-(void)scrollBackground:(ccTime)dt
{
    CGSize s = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

    CGPoint pos1 = mBG1.position;
    CGPoint pos2 = mBG2.position;

    pos1.x += MM_BG_SPEED_DUR;
    pos2.x += MM_BG_SPEED_DUR;


    if(pos1.x >= (s.width*0.5f) )
    {
        pos1.x = pos2.x - s.width;
    }

    if(pos2.x >= (s.width*0.5f) )
    {
        pos2.x = pos1.x - s.width;
    }

    mBG1.position = pos1;
    mBG2.position = pos2;

}
```

Comment: thnaks.. previously i was trying -(pos2.x + s.width;) thats y it was not working.. but with ur answer its working now

Comment: It works, but you are changing when edge of the texture is on center of the screen. Good to change when it is on corner. -:)

Comment: Yeah, true @Guru. Should be able to just remove the `*0.5f` in the if statement for that...